Minor pause between loop transitions with R3 engine when used with ExoPlayer(Android)
I have integrated the Rubberband library with ExoPlayer for pitch and tempo adjustments in an Android project. When using the R2 engine, audio looping works smoothly as expected. However, when switching to the R3 engine(OptionEngineFiner) with looping enabled in exoplayer, there is a minor but noticeable pause between the end and the start of the audio file during loop transitions. This behavior does not occur with the R2 engine(OptionEngineFaster) and only affects the R3 engine, leading to an inconsistent looping experience.
Is there anything I am missing with the R3 engine? I have tried the Rubberband demo app, and looping works fine there.
My AudioProcessor code for exoplayer:
rb = RubberBandStretcher(
                    inputAudioFormat.sampleRate,
                    inputAudioFormat.channelCount,
                    RubberBandStretcher.OptionProcessRealTime.or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionEngineFiner).or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionWindowShort).or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionFormantPreserved).or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionPitchHighConsistency),
                    speed.toDouble(),
                    pitch.toDouble()
                )

Whole code for Audio Processor
class RubberBandAudioProcessor : AudioProcessor {

    /** Indicates that the output sample rate should be the same as the input.  */
    val SAMPLE_RATE_NO_CHANGE = -1

    /** The threshold below which the difference between two pitch/speed factors is negligible.  */
    private val CLOSE_THRESHOLD = 0.0001f

    /**
     * The minimum number of output bytes required for duration scaling to be calculated using the
     * input and output byte counts, rather than using the current playback speed.
     */
    private val MIN_BYTES_FOR_DURATION_SCALING_CALCULATION = 1024

    private var pendingOutputSampleRate = 0
    private var speed = 1f
    private var pitch = 1f

    private var pendingInputAudioFormat: AudioProcessor.AudioFormat
    private var pendingOutputAudioFormat: AudioProcessor.AudioFormat
    private var inputAudioFormat: AudioProcessor.AudioFormat
    private var outputAudioFormat: AudioProcessor.AudioFormat

    private var pendingSonicRecreation = false
    private var rb: RubberBandStretcher? = null
    private var buffer: ByteBuffer
    private var shortBuffer: ShortBuffer
    private var outputBuffer: ByteBuffer
    private var inputBytes: Long = 0
    private var outputBytes: Long = 0
    private var inputEnded = false

    /** Creates a new Sonic audio processor.  */
    init {
        speed = 1f
        pitch = 1f
        pendingInputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        pendingOutputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        inputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        outputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        buffer = AudioProcessor.EMPTY_BUFFER
        shortBuffer = buffer.asShortBuffer()
        outputBuffer = AudioProcessor.EMPTY_BUFFER
        pendingOutputSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE_NO_CHANGE
    }

    /**
     * Sets the target playback speed. This method may only be called after draining data through the
     * processor. The value returned by [.isActive] may change, and the processor must be
     * [flushed][.flush] before queueing more data.
     *
     * @param speed The target factor by which playback should be sped up.
     */
    fun setSpeed(speed: Float) {
        if (this.speed != speed) {
            this.speed = 1/speed
            rb?.timeRatio = 1/speed.toDouble()
            pendingSonicRecreation = true
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the target playback pitch. This method may only be called after draining data through the
     * processor. The value returned by [.isActive] may change, and the processor must be
     * [flushed][.flush] before queueing more data.
     *
     * @param pitch The target pitch.
     */
    fun setPitch(pitch: Float) {
        if (this.pitch != pitch) {
            this.pitch = pitch
            rb?.pitchScale=pitch.toDouble()
            pendingSonicRecreation = true
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the sample rate for output audio, in Hertz. Pass [.SAMPLE_RATE_NO_CHANGE] to output
     * audio at the same sample rate as the input. After calling this method, call [ ][.configure] to configure the processor with the new sample rate.
     *
     * @param sampleRateHz The sample rate for output audio, in Hertz.
     * @see .configure
     */
    fun setOutputSampleRateHz(sampleRateHz: Int) {
        pendingOutputSampleRate = sampleRateHz
    }

    /**
     * Returns the media duration corresponding to the specified playout duration, taking speed
     * adjustment into account.
     *
     *
     * The scaling performed by this method will use the actual playback speed achieved by the
     * audio processor, on average, since it was last flushed. This may differ very slightly from the
     * target playback speed.
     *
     * @param playoutDuration The playout duration to scale.
     * @return The corresponding media duration, in the same units as `duration`.
     */
    fun getMediaDuration(playoutDuration: Long): Long {
        return if (outputBytes >= MIN_BYTES_FOR_DURATION_SCALING_CALCULATION) {
            val processedInputBytes = inputBytes - Assertions.checkNotNull(rb).samplesRequired
            if (outputAudioFormat.sampleRate == inputAudioFormat.sampleRate) Util.scaleLargeTimestamp(
                playoutDuration,
                processedInputBytes,
                outputBytes
            ) else Util.scaleLargeTimestamp(
                playoutDuration,
                processedInputBytes * outputAudioFormat.sampleRate,
                outputBytes * inputAudioFormat.sampleRate
            )
        } else {
            (speed.toDouble() * playoutDuration).toLong()
        }
    }

    @Throws(UnhandledAudioFormatException::class)
    override fun configure(inputAudioFormat: AudioProcessor.AudioFormat): AudioProcessor.AudioFormat {
        if (inputAudioFormat.encoding != C.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) {
            throw UnhandledAudioFormatException(inputAudioFormat)
        }
        val outputSampleRateHz =
            if (pendingOutputSampleRate == SAMPLE_RATE_NO_CHANGE) inputAudioFormat.sampleRate else pendingOutputSampleRate
        pendingInputAudioFormat = inputAudioFormat
        pendingOutputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat(
            outputSampleRateHz,
            inputAudioFormat.channelCount,
            C.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
        )

        pendingSonicRecreation = true
        return pendingOutputAudioFormat
    }

    override fun isActive(): Boolean {
        val outputSampleRate = pendingOutputAudioFormat.sampleRate
        val inputSampleRate = pendingInputAudioFormat.sampleRate
        val speedDifference = abs(speed - 1f)
        val pitchDifference = abs(pitch - 1f)

        val isOutputSampleRateValid = outputSampleRate != Format.NO_VALUE
        val isSpeedChanged = speedDifference >= CLOSE_THRESHOLD
        val isPitchChanged = pitchDifference >= CLOSE_THRESHOLD
        val isSampleRateDifferent = outputSampleRate != inputSampleRate
        return (isOutputSampleRateValid
                && (isSpeedChanged || isPitchChanged || isSampleRateDifferent))
    }


    override fun queueInput(inputBuffer: ByteBuffer) {
        if (!inputBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
            return
        }
        val rb = Assertions.checkNotNull(rb)
        val shortBuffer = inputBuffer.asShortBuffer()
        val inputSize = inputBuffer.remaining()
        inputBytes += inputSize.toLong()
        rb.process(shortBuffer, inputAudioFormat.channelCount, false)
        inputBuffer.position(inputBuffer.position() + inputSize)
    }

    override fun queueEndOfStream() {
        Log.e("RUBBERBANDAUDIOPROCESSOR","QueueEndOfStream");
        if (rb != null) {
            rb!!.queueEndOfStream()
        }
        inputEnded = true
    }

    override fun getOutput(): ByteBuffer {

        val rb = rb
        val channelCount = inputAudioFormat.channelCount
        val samplesRequired = rb?.samplesRequired
        if (rb != null) {
            val outputSize = rb.available()
            if (outputSize > 0) {
                if (buffer.capacity() < outputSize * channelCount * 2) {
                    buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(outputSize * channelCount * 2)
                        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
                    shortBuffer = buffer.asShortBuffer()
                } else {
                    buffer.clear()
                    shortBuffer.clear()
                }
                val retrieved = rb.retrieve(shortBuffer, channelCount)
                outputBytes += retrieved.toLong() * channelCount * 2
                buffer.limit(retrieved * channelCount * 2)
                outputBuffer = buffer
            }
        }
        val outputBuffer = outputBuffer
        this.outputBuffer = AudioProcessor.EMPTY_BUFFER
        return outputBuffer
    }

    override fun isEnded(): Boolean {
        Log.e("inputeEnded", inputEnded.toString())
        Log.e("rb", rb.toString())
        val samplesRequired= rb?.samplesRequired

        Log.e("rb sample required", samplesRequired.toString())

       // return inputEnded && (rb == null || samplesRequired == 0)
        return inputEnded
    }

    override fun flush() {
        val isAct=isActive();
        Log.e("IsActive", isAct.toString())

        if (isAct) {
            Log.e("pendingSonicRecreation", pendingSonicRecreation.toString()  )
            inputAudioFormat = pendingInputAudioFormat
            outputAudioFormat = pendingOutputAudioFormat
            if (pendingSonicRecreation) {

                rb = RubberBandStretcher(
                    inputAudioFormat.sampleRate,
                    inputAudioFormat.channelCount,
                    RubberBandStretcher.OptionProcessRealTime.or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionEngineFiner).or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionWindowShort).or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionFormantPreserved).or(RubberBandStretcher.OptionPitchHighConsistency),
                    speed.toDouble(),
                    pitch.toDouble()
                )


            } else if (rb != null) {

                rb!!.reset()
            }
        }
        outputBuffer = AudioProcessor.EMPTY_BUFFER
        inputBytes = 0
        outputBytes = 0
        inputEnded = false
    }

    override fun reset() {
        speed = 1f
        pitch = 1f
        pendingInputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        pendingOutputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        inputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        outputAudioFormat = AudioProcessor.AudioFormat.NOT_SET
        buffer = AudioProcessor.EMPTY_BUFFER
        shortBuffer = buffer.asShortBuffer()
        outputBuffer = AudioProcessor.EMPTY_BUFFER
        pendingOutputSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE_NO_CHANGE
        pendingSonicRecreation = false
        rb = null
        inputBytes = 0
        outputBytes = 0
        inputEnded = false
    }
}

I have tried changing buffer size.
